# after migration To X64: CComPtr CoCreateInstance failed with rc=0x80040154 Class not registered

Tags: visual-studio-2015, com, migration, 64-bit, middleware

after migration  To X64: CComPtr CoCreateInstance failed with rc=0x80040154 Class not registered

The IDL File did not changed

```
//import "objidl.idl";
//import "ICmConnection.idl";
//import "ICmNamedObject.idl";
//import "ipositio.idl";
//import "oaidl.idl";
//import "ocidl.idl";
import "objidl.idl";
import "ICmConnection.idl";
import "ICmNamedObject.idl";
import "ipositio.idl";


[ 
  uuid (96c64c60-24f6-99d0-9f8c-0020af9099cc),
  //uuid (E2123FC4-0D5D-4A8F-94BC-6582D9F84109),
  object, 
  pointer_default(unique)
]
interface ICMTopologieDatabase : IUnknown  /*IDispatch */{
  HRESULT GetObjects      ( [in] unsigned classID, [out] ICMPosition** devices   );
  HRESULT NewObject       ( [in] unsigned classID, [out] ICmNamedObject** device );
  HRESULT getNamedDevice2 ( [in] LPSTR name      , [out] ICmNamedObject** device );
  HRESULT InitializeClient();
}
```

i aded for the  MIDL Compiler options /env x64 /x64 for X64
when  i checked for the uuid 96c64c60-24f6-99d0-9f8c-0020af9099cc in the widows registry it was not found at all.

when i checked the  Files which the MIDL Complier Generate i could see that it was possibly not may was not correct switch to X64

```
/* Compiler settings for D:\Home\Atiras\V77Ma_64Bit_Branch001\Src\Cm\NmsCmCommon\ITopolog.idl:
    Oicf, W1, Zp8, env=Win64 (32b run), target_arch=AMD64 8.00.0603 
    protocol : dce , ms_ext, c_ext, robust
    error checks: none
    VC __declspec() decoration level: 
         __declspec(uuid()), __declspec(selectany), __declspec(novtable)
         DECLSPEC_UUID(), MIDL_INTERFACE()
*/
```

can it be that  with this MIDL compiler settings the are  not created any registry an the class is not registered an what are the correct switches then ?

Comment: 0x80040154 is typically a registry issue like your component is registered for x86 registry and the client is compiled for x64 or the reverse.

Comment: This may be the problem when e try to register the dll containing the class with   "C:\WINDOWS\System32\regsvr32.exe" /C /S NmsCmCommon.dll"  i get the error rc=4  there must be a problem with the dll